# Incomplete View Loading Before Firebase GetRecord is Resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, route-provider

I'm having a problem loading a record from firebase into my view when directly linking to the intended route with the key as a routeParam. As shown below in my routeProvider I've specified the param later called in the SpecController. The problem is, if I directly type the url in or click an offsite link the model bindings are all "undefined" indicating that the record is not loaded.

```
// Snippet from RouteProvider
.when('/spec/:urlKey', {
  templateUrl: 'views/spec.html',
  controller: 'SpecController',
  controllerAs: 'spec'
})

// Snippet from SpecController
var cKey = $routeParams.urlKey;
this.check = this.checkList.$getRecord(cKey);
```

After a bit of research it seems I should call a resolve in the routeprovider and run that second bit of code. Though I'm not sure if that's the problem or if it has to do with the way angular loads itself and the routeparams as well as the order thereof.

Just as a side note it is fully functional when I load the application from a separate route/view and then click a link within the application which then uses $location to set the url and param as shown below.

```
// Snippet from ListController
this.viewCheck = function(check){
  var ref = this.checkList.$keyAt(check);
  $location.path('/spec/'+ref);
};
```

The "key" I'm referring to as well as all other additional functions I'm using and referring to can be found directly at the following section of the Firebase API Guide: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-arrays

I can't really reproduce the issue in a fiddle because the only way it happens is if you directly place the link in the url of a browser. I've made a small video showing the problem. When the video opens you see the result of entering the url directly, then by simply clicking "Home" and then "Back" it then loads appropriately. http://screencast.com/t/4OKRTVnc

Comment: This is extremely ambiguous and obfuscated. Can you provide steps to reproduce? Enough code to generate an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What are the values of ckey? Does that key exist in the database? How have you determined it doesn't "load"? What URLs are you using? Are you using HTML5 history and URL rewrites? Versions? Clues? Solutions to world peace? (okay, the last one was a stretch)

Comment: @Kato I will edit my question to provide a more robust explanation, I just assumed (and we know what that does) this was something that was typical in the angular library when dealing with routeProvider. Maybe I'm supposed to use $loaded in some way? I'm not entirely sure as I'm still a bit new to AngularFire as a whole and I don't know exactly how to implement it. I certainly appreciate the help! *Question Updated*

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is making more sense. But I feel a couple key parts of reproducing (and thus understanding) the issue are still missing. What URL is being typed in to the browser? How did you determine the "model bindings" are undefined (and where are those in the example)? If you want to use $loaded in a resolve function, that's [covered here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-routes)--just return checkList.$loaded() instead of Auth.$requireAuth().

Comment: @Kato From the default view (Run by ListController) if I click a link it creates the url as shown in the above snippet: "mydomain.com/directory/index.html/#/spec/-{Firebase Key} (Example: -JsdfksjSSekjfo4333_ALka). This results in the page loading properly, however if you copy that link and place it directly in a "new tab" for example it will not load properly. Essentially the input fields are blank, the svg justgauge plugin shows undefined, and all dynamic text normally on the page is simply missing.

Comment: @Kato There is something very interesting about the situation... If I input desired URL into a new tab or window and then click on "home" (any page just using as an example) it will of course load that page properly. If I THEN click the "back" button in the browser it will of course navigate to the previous page (the URL I entered) and it WILL load the page properly! This is why I'm assuming it has something to do with Angular not collecting the routeParam in the URL after loading.

Comment: do you have a fiddle showcasing the problem?

Comment: @dnozay Unfortunately the problem has to do with the way it is acting within the browser. I can't really reproduce the issue in a fiddle because the only way it happens is if you directly place the link in the url of a browser. I've made a small video showing the problem. When the video opens you see the result of entering the url directly, then by simply clicking "Home" and then "Back" it then loads appropriately. http://screencast.com/t/4OKRTVnc

Comment: Okay, so what I'm actually starting to think now is that it has nothing to do with the routeParam at all. I believe it might have to do with the fact that Angular isn't waiting to hear back from firebase before displaying the view. However, I'm not sure why it's perfectly able to do so with Angular already being loaded (IE Navigating between routes/views) and why it only seems to have the problem whenever I directly type the URL in to a new window/tab.

Comment: If you have a controller that is dependent on values loaded asynchronously in any way (within the same controller or from a service), you should provide a promise (for instance using $q) to which you can attach code to run when the data is loaded. In some instances you may have to run $scope.$apply() or $rootScope.$apply() to have the gui refresh.

Comment: In your case, firebase is loading data asynchronously. I am guessing this happens in a service which is not ready if you restart the app (typing url), but is ready if you don't restart but only change view (navigate back/forth within the same application)

Comment: @jornare That sounds about right can you provide a code example of the promise in an answer and I'll give it a shot and gladly award you the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use the Angular route resolution process based on promises.  Here is a [working plunkr demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/Maiscc?p=preview), but the highlights are:

**Build a Data Service that Returns Angularfire's Promises**

There are many, many ways to structure and access your Firebase data, but the important thing here is to use the promises returned by Angularfire.  This keeps you from making duplicate sync objects for the same data, and allows you to play nice with Angular.

```
testApp.factory("ChatDataService", ["$firebase", 
  function ($firebase) {
    var rootRef = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/");
    var chatDataService = {};

    chatDataService.getChatRooms = function () {
      if (!chatDataService.chatRoomsPromise) {
        var chatRoomRef = rootRef.child("web/data/rooms");
        var chatRooms = $firebase(chatRoomRef).$asArray();
        chatDataService.chatRoomsPromise = chatRooms.$loaded();
      }
      return chatDataService.chatRoomsPromise;
    };

    chatDataService.getRoom = function (roomId) {
      return chatDataService.getChatRooms()
        .then(function (chatRooms) {
          return chatRooms.$getRecord(roomId);
        });
    };

    chatDataService.getRoomMessages = function (roomId) {
      if (!chatDataService.messages || !chatDataService.messages[roomId]) {
        chatDataService.messages = chatDataService.messages || {};
        var roomMessagesRef = rootRef.child("web/data/messages").child(roomId);
        var roomMessages = $firebase(roomMessagesRef).$asArray();
        chatDataService.messages[roomId] = roomMessages.$loaded();
      }
      return chatDataService.messages[roomId];
    }; 

    return chatDataService;
  }
]);
```

**Return Promises From Resolve Functions**

You can write a small route resolution function that uses your data service to get the correct data.  Make sure you return a promise.

```
  when("/room/:roomId", {
      controller: "RoomController",
      resolve: {
          room: ["$route", "ChatDataService", function ($route, chatDataService) {
              var roomId = $route.current.params.roomId;
              return chatDataService.getRoom(roomId);
          }],
          messages: ["$route", "ChatDataService", function ($route, chatDataService) {
              var roomId = $route.current.params.roomId;
              return chatDataService.getRoomMessages(roomId);
          }]

      },
      templateUrl: "roomView.html"
  })
```

**Keep Your Controllers Dumb**

You could have done all the Firebase lookup and promise resolving in each controller.  In this case, I kept the controllers dumb by letting Angular routing wait on promise resolution.

```
testApp.controller("RoomController", ["$scope", "$firebase", "room", "messages",
  function ($scope, $firebase, room, messages) {
    $scope.room = room;
    $scope.messages = messages; 
  }
]);
```